# Dell T110 II Server 2008 R2 Installation

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, software-raid

I have a Dell T110 II with 2 1TB drives in raid 1 using the S100 on board raid.  When I load Server 2008 R2 it says, "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click OK."  I've never dealt with this situation before can someone point me in the right direction on how to get the OS installed?

Thanks!
msindle

Comment: Does the T110 II have the Dell Lifecycle Controller? If so, you can launch the Lifecycle Controller on boot and use it to install the OS, including the Dell drivers for the HDD/RAID controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting to the OpenManage DVD that came with your system, select Install OS, then insert your 2008 R2 DVD when prompted.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I purchased the server with no OS or openmanage software.  I was going to try and put my MSDN license on this server to help save cost.

Comment: I ended up snagging an OpenManage disk from another server install and that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Dell shows that there has been at least two firmware, bios updates for the motherboard between 9 to 6 months ago.
Additionally there are also firmware updates for raid and S 100 drivers for Windows 2008 are two drivers. Please note the date April 17, 2012.

Dell driver link
http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/poweredge-t110-2